# Everyone's OK with indirect anagrams, right?

Tags: cryptic-clues

> 22nd of May turned out not so fine! (6)

Oh, and did I mention topical?

Comment: Is the title part of the riddle? I doubt it but I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: @SamHarrington It's a cryptic crossword clue, but it breaks one of the rules (no indirect anagrams) which is why it's here and not part of a crossword.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with the {Znapurfgre obzovat ynfg lrne}?

Comment: @gnovice No, it doesn't.

Comment: "Topical" just means about today, May 22nd.

Comment: I was convinced it was about last year. Tomorrow will not turn out so fine? Spoiler alert!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A rough attempt is the word:

> COARSE

With the following indirect reasoning:

> '22nd of May' is the twenty second of May, so twenty = score and second of May = a
>
>   'turned out' indicates to anagram *scorea* giving **coarse** which means 'not so fine'.

Comment: LOL at the first 3 words of your answer!

Comment: Ha! 22nd as Twenty Second. Nice. Also,it's not an &lit?

Comment: @Sid, I don't think it's an &lit. Wordplay and definition seem fairly well separated as I read it.

Comment: @Rupert I kinda expected it because of that exclamation mark in the clue. Guess I was wrong.

Comment: I put that in because of the indirect anagram. Probably didn't need it with the huge flashing "indirect anagram" alert above it.

Comment: (@RupertMorrish You'd probably want a ? instead to call out a non-standard element or interpretation, no?)